# Comma in json string causes json.loads to fail with "Unterminated string starting at:"

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

This is my test command:

```
curl -v -A 'TEST/1.0' -X POST -d 'events=[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset;123"}]' 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/_api'
```

This is my RequestHandler

```
   class MyWebhookHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def post(self):
         events_json = self.request.get('events')
         event_datum = json.loads(events_json) # exception here
```

Whenever I reach the `json.loads` line, I got this exception:

```
    event_datum = json.loads(events_json)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 27 (char 26)
```

What can I do to stop this exception?

**EDIT**

The problem is probably has more to do with `self.request.get('events')` than the json library. The function call returns

```
[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset
```

Instead of

```
[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset;123"}]
```

Comment: Can you post the json string... at least the first 27 chars?

Comment: @tdelaney Can you see the string following `-d` of the curl command in question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are sending in your request a list, not a string `events=[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset;123"}]`  you should use

```
'{"events":[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset;123"}]}'
```

Comment: The question is about google app engine. And I am not having multiple values here ('events' key contains **one** json string)

Comment: @AnthonyKong you are not sending a string, you are sending a list, check it out.

Comment: I see now. The test command is given to me by a third party and I did not think it through if it is valid or not. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The other user did not provide a correct answer. The issue is not that you need to use a different python function to get the POST request parameter - `get` is the correct function to use here in order to grab the request string - the issue is that you are not sending a valid JSON object. You're sending a javascript expression that assigns a JSON object to a variable `events`. JSON is a *subset* of javascript expressions, but not the same thing.

Instead, you should be using:

```
curl -v -A 'TEST/1.0' -X POST -d '[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset;123"}]' 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/_api'
```

or

```
curl -v -A 'TEST/1.0' -X POST -d '{"events":[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset;123"}]}' 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/_api'
```

Answer (score -1):

';' in the post-data is considered a separator, in the same way '&' normally would be, so the value for 'events' ends at that point and there will be an empty value present for `123"}]`.
You should encode the string in your curl line:

```
'events=[{"event":"reset", "test":"reset%38123"}]'
```

If you did the post via, say, jQuery with $.post this encoding would happen automatically.